# Android Version 4.2.1 - Wifi HotSpot - WiFi connection from Windows 7 keeps on disconnecting

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, android

I use WiFi hotspot from my Android Phone for getting internet connection on Windows 7. It works without any problem at home, but at office, it connects and keeps on disconnecting randomly in interval of 30 seconds - 5 minutes.

Why is this happening only at office and not at home? Is there any solution for this?

Comment: You probably have interference with other wireless networks around your office on the same channel as the one your hotspot is using. Can you configure the hotspot settings? The reason I say this is that your work networks will probably not be easily reconfigured because one person has a hotspot problem...

Comment: How can I change the Channel for hotspot on my phone? And what range should I choose. Are there any parameters for choosing the range?

Comment: Android 4.3 on Galaxy S3: Go to `Settings` -> `Connections` -> `More Networks` -> `Tethering and portable hotspot` -> turn on portable hotspot switch -> `Configure` button -> tick `show advanced settings` to reveal the channel selector.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will try to update the Android Version on my phone.

Comment: You may be able to do the same settings with your 4.2.1... possibly not under the same menus but look around

Comment: It is not there. I have browsed through all the Menus and Settings.

Comment: You may have a version of Android that doesn't support being able to change the hotspot channel...